# Why has my internet speed dropped down?

Tags: 14.04, internet, hardware, download-speed

I recently switched to Ubuntu. I've been having a lot of internet troubles ever since. I used Windows 7 before.

I've had trouble loading web pages, and it would take a solid minute or two to even start displaying anything.

Why is this?

How can I fix this?

Details:

Ubuntu 14.04

Here's a comparison: 
Speedtest on my phone:

[image: https://www.speedtest.net/android/854963623.png]

Speedtest on my PC:

[image: https://www.speedtest.net/result/3553607783.png]

Taken about 30 seconds apart.

EDIT: [Complete information on wifi.](http://pastebin.com/MyByAyum)

Comment: Add details on (ADSL) modem OR WiFi being used, and Ubuntu version. *This is likely a driver issue, or upstream (your ISP).*

Comment: Please add the output of these commands as well: `iwconfig`, `lsusb -v` and `lspci -v`

Comment: Please run the script is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: @WildMan I added all of the information as a pastebin link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see that you are using Nexus4

how about tethering your device to Ubuntu?

btw what method that u r using to connect your phone with Ubuntu?

USB tether? or Wifi?

Comment: My Nexus 4 is connected through wifi, and my computer is also connectedto wifi.

Comment: Thank you, using my phone to tether boosted  the speed right up. Is there any permanent fix, though?